# How to check if a file exists inside /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/MY_UUID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

How can I check that a file exists inside a folder with this format:

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/MY_UUID ?

I found examples but they seem to designed to work with different locations, like documents and stuff like that.

However I'm fairly new with objective C.

Comment: where is your folder ?

Comment: you can't its you actual device parameter.

Comment: The image I'm looking for is inside the UUID folder, its not really UUID, its a bunch of numbers.

Comment: you have check to if ([NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistAtPath:urpath])